# How to transfer a file(PDF) to Hadoop file system

Tags: file, hadoop, copy, hortonworks-sandbox

I have Hortonworks system in place and want to copy file from a file system to Hadoop. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
hadoop fs -put /your/local/file.pdf /your/hdfs/location
```

or

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /your/local/file.pdf /your/hdfs/location
```

refer [put command](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put)

Comment: Thank you for reply

hdfs dfs -put SRC Dest

In above command can we have SRC as a remote location.

I want to read files from a remote location and save it in HDFS

Comment: remote location must have to be part of your hadoop cluster , part as in it should be one of the data nodes.

If not then you have to use other data transfer tools for transferring data to HDFS like: apache flume is one simple example